# How to retrieve value from arraylist according to time interval?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I am trying to fetch a URL and when I fetch that URL I get a string. The string I kept in my `arraylist`. Now I want to print `arraylist` value. The condition is that only 15 values should print every x seconds.

Here is my code:

```
public class CommoditywiseGetUrl {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        URL url;
        try {
            // get URL content

            String a = "http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=paddy";
            url = new URL(a);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = inputLine.replace("|", "\n");

                s = s.replace("~", " ");
                //System.out.println(s);
                StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
                while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();

                    String price = str.nextElement().toString();


                    list1.add(mandi);
                    list2.add(price);
                }
            }
            String item1 = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                item1 = list1.get(i);
                System.out.println("mandi" + item1);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
                String item2 = list2.get(i);
                System.out.println("Price" + item2);
            }

            br.close();

            //System.out.println(sb);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I reach my desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: u can calculate time interval and use Thread.sleep() before entering item to arraylist....

Comment: You can use wait() and notify(). Or you can do it using System.currentTimeMillis() + interval;

Comment: can u write  small code for me

Comment: I *really* hope that isn't a live IP address connecting to anything sensitive.

Comment: This question is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Your list population logic is not related to the scheduled printing of the list elements. So better not mix them. I would recommend you use java util Timer to schedule the printing for fine grained control.
I am not able to run your code, but here is an idea on how you can use timer:

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RunMeTask(), 1000,60000); // executes every 60 secs with 1 sec delay
```

And the RumeMetask would probably look like

```
 public static class RunMeTask extends TimerTask
{

        @Override
        public void run() {
              String item1 = null;
                for (int i = count; i < 16; i++) {
                    item1 = list1.get(i);
                    System.out.println("mandi" + item1);
                }
                for (int i = count; i < 16; i++) {
                    String item2 = list2.get(i);
                    System.out.println("Price" + item2);
                }

        }

     }
```

Comment: den u tell me how can i show  every 15 value only 10 sec